# IDLE (Python GUI) Will Not Open

Tags: arcpy, gdal, installation, python-2.7, idle

I recently went through a lengthy process of installing GDAL and think that something may have gone awry as my IDLE is not opening. I cannot edit files in IDLE either. The only thing that works is running the IDLE.bat which then opens the Python Shell. I do have Python 2.7 installed via Arc (thus my installation for Python is in C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.4).

[image: Python Issues]

I've tried copying the tcl8.5 folder into the Lib folder. I've cleared the files in my .idlerc folder. Short of reinstalling Arc entirely, are there any workarounds? I can't seem to find much else that helps.As you can see in the photos, my .py files have also lost their default programs even though pythonw is set as the default program.

Can't seem to add a proper photos link, but the photos are at https://i.stack.imgur.com/rpV6Y.jpg

Answer (score 2):

You can try a repair install of Arc...

I had similar issues with python acting up on my work machine when I was messing around with Python 3. I uninstalled py 3 but the issues persisted. Once I performed a repair install (control panel, click uninstall, select the repair install option) which fixed my issues.

And much quicker than doing a full uninstall and reinstall.